# Retrieve original string prior to interpolation

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, literals

I want to write a small patch to String class for my test environment that will warn for usage of double quotes without interpolation (`#{foo}`).

1. Is there a way to resolve if a string has derived from interpolation?
2. If yes, is there a way to retrieve the original un-interpolated value?

Comment: You can look at rubocop gem, i think it does what you want. (It raises an error when using double quote without interpolation). I'm looking at the source code in github to find how they manage to do it. [rubocop source code](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop)

Comment: Thanks but I think they parse the source which is not what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: You are misunderstanding something. There is no "original string prior to interpolation"; a string is created after interpolation has been done. What you are trying to do is impossible at the Ruby level. The only way to do it is to parse the source, as LolWalid suggests, or hack the Ruby code at the C-level.

Comment: You can try to escape all interpolation characters (`#`, `{`, and `}`) in the code and apply `Ripper.sexp` to it, but that still requires parsing the source.

Comment: @sawa Ehhh, you're absolutely right. Can you post your clarification as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "original string prior to interpolation"; a string is created after interpolation has been done. What you are trying to do is impossible at the Ruby level. The only way to do it is to parse the source, as LolWalid suggests, or hack the Ruby code at the C level.